# How do I determine if the values are unique, then take the sum of the booleans?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to determine if the values in my dataframe are unique as booleans, (true, false) then count the ones that are unique so where unique is true.

Here is what I have so far:

`c=~df[col].duplicated(keep=False).sum()`

I'm not sure if I can add `.sum()` at the end of this or if there is another way to do it?

Comment: Can you add an example input and output?

Comment: `df.duplicated().any()`